# C# access Active Directory as another user

Tags: c#, active-directory, impersonation

I'd like to ask for your help with following issue. I am working on ad-hoc application, will be used only by me and just once.

Part of it is to perform password reset for over 3000 users in AD and send them new credentials.

I can read from AD as normal user, but I have to use privileged account to modify it. How can I do that? I know, I can use PowerShell and have it done in a seconds, but I'd like to learn how to do it in C#.

My code to search for user is simple

```
public class ADSecurity
{
    public static string getUserName(string sam)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sam);
        return user.Name;
    }
}
```

How can I do the same, but as different user?

I've seen some guides, but none of them explained a-z ... just advice on how to impersonate, but nothing about how to use it. There was one article here about impersonation, but using LDAP protocol (`DirectoryEntry`). But as I understand, it is really slow.

Any advice appreciated. I need to run it 2 days from now, so in worst case scenario I use PowerShell to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it:

1. Run your application under the needed credentials (Shift+right-click on the .exe file and use 'Run as a different user'). If you're just doing this once, this is the easiest.
2. Use the [`PrincipalContext` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_ContextType_System_String_System_String_System_String_) that accepts a username and password.

```
public class ADSecurity
{
    public static string getUserName(string sam)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, username, password);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sam);
        return user.Name;
    }
}
```

3. Use the [`DirectoryEntry` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryEntry__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_) that accepts a username and password.

I'm not sure which example you're talking about that's "slow", but in my experience, using `DirectoryEntry` directly is almost always faster, as long as you use it correctly. The `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace (what you are using in your example) uses `DirectoryEntry` behind the scenes anyway.

Of course, options 2 & 3 require you know the password.

Comment: Option 2 looks exactly as what I was looking for. I was not really wise from what I read about System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, but apparently, I should look deeper. :-) 
P.S: our company has strict rules when it comes to accounts. With my privileged account I can technically "wipe" the domain, but can't use it to run any app, service, scheduled task or to log in to any computer.
P.P.S: Thaaaaaaanks!